# User wise Grouping in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table, ngfor

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                
                  <th scope="col">Username</th>
                  <th scope="col">Cash</th>
                  <th scope="col">Credit</th>
                              
                  
                  <th scope="col">Accounttype</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let sale of sales">   
               
                  <td>{{ sale.account.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{ sale.cash}}</td>
                  <td>{{ sale.credit }}</td>
                
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here is my table,

I want to group same Usernames in first row, do not want them separate columns,

eg:

Username Cash Credit
Nadula   1500  6900
8000  6200
9000  5400
6500  3900
5600  1000

I wan to Userwisegropup and display details? How can I do that in html?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you show sample data and a table like you imagine?

Comment: Username Cash Credit Total
Big Plate 50000 104000     154000
Big Plate 6000 0              36000   ,                                                                      this is the table I am getting right now, but I want to  have only one 'Big Plate; column and display details, like this,                                                                                                                 Username Cash Credit Total
Big Plate     50000       104000 154000
             60000  36000       36000

Comment: like [this](https://i.imgur.com/4EYC51H.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have `sales` defined somewhere. Maybe in the component? If so, then it would be best to format/process your data so that displaying it would be more straightforward. Otherwise, the template could loop over them using some pipe to order and filter.

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Cash</th>
      <th scope="col">Credit</th>

      <th scope="col">Accounttype</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let sale of sales | sortBy; index as i">
      <ng-container *ngIf="sales[i - 1]?.account.name === sale.account.name">
        <td></td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="sales[i - 1]?.account.name !== sale.account.name">
        <td>{{ sale.account.name }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <td>{{ sale.cash }}</td>
      <td>{{ sale.credit }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  sales = [
    { account: { name: 'John' }, cash: 100, credit: 100 },
    { account: { name: 'John' }, cash: 300, credit: 300 },
    { account: { name: 'Bob' }, cash: 200, credit: 200 },
    { account: { name: 'John' }, cash: 400, credit: 400 },
    { account: { name: 'Bill' }, cash: 300, credit: 400 }
  ];
}


/*
 *ngFor="let c of oneDimArray | sortBy:'asc'"
 *ngFor="let c of arrayOfObjects | sortBy:'asc':'propertyName'"
*/
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'sortBy' })
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[]): any[] {
    function compare( a, b ) {
      if ( a['account']['name'] < b['account']['name'] ){
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a['account']['name'] > b['account']['name'] ){
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    
    return value.sort( compare );
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-mxjaaj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts